# ModuleNotFoundError error with PyCharm project folder recs

Tags: python, python-import

I am working on a project in PyCharm.  The project has the following structure:

```
/projectRoot/
   folder1/
       somecode.py
   utils/
       __init__.py
       myutils1.py
```

I'd want to know how I can do an import such that the import works when running the code in the pyCharm console in an interactive manner, as well as when running the code using the

```
python somecode.py
```

command in the terminal.

Currently I do:

`from utils.myutils1.py import myClass`

But command line I get the error:

> File "somecode.py", line 10, in 
>       from utils.myutils1 import myClass ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

and on PyCharm:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
>   "/home/ubuntu/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/IPython/core/interactiveshell.py",
>   line 2881, in run_code
>       exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)   File "", line 1, in 
>       from utils.myutils1 import myClass ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'

Any recommendations on the proper folder structure for modules within a project, and how to import them properly?

Thanks!

Comment: right click on projectRoot , and select mark directory as, sources root

Comment: @JoranBeasley thanks! I did but I still get the same error...

Comment: which python version on are you using?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

To explain the answer I recreated that project structure you had

```
/projectRoot/
   folder1/
       somecode.py
   utils/
       __init__.py
       myutils1.py
```

**somecode.py**

```
from utils.myutils1 import myclass

if __name__ == "__main__":
   print(myclass)
```

**myutils1.py**

```
myclass="tarun"
```

Running them from pycharm works without any issues, but running them from terminal will produce below error

```
  File "somecode.py", line XX, in <module>
    from utils.myutils1 import myclass
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'utils'
```

The issue is that Pycharm does few things for you, which is why it is not working in the terminal. So before telling you what you need to, I will tell you two things that PyCharm does on its own.

**Python Console**

When you launch a Python Console from Pycharm, there is some code that gets executed, using preferences.

[image: Python Console]

As you can see there are two options

```
[X] Add content roots to PYTHONPATH
[ ] Add source roots to PYTHONPATH
```

And then a starting script as well. So what this does is that it adds the root of your project to python's path. Which is controlled by two main ways `sys.path` and `PYTHONPATH` environment variable

If I run the below code in Python Console

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path
['/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev', 
'/Applications/PyCharm.app/Contents/helpers/pydev', 
'/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/folderstructure27/lib/python27.zip', 
'/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/folderstructure27/lib/python2.7', ....
'/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/folderstructure27/lib/python2.7/site-packages', 
'/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/payu/projects/folderstructure27']
```

As you can see `'/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/payu/projects/folderstructure27'` is added to the Python terminal.

**Python Configurations**

When you configure to RUN in code using Pycharm, you have similar two options.

[image: Run configurations]

We can change the code of our `somecode.py` to below

```
import os
print (os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])

import sys
print (sys.path)

/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/payu/projects/folderstructure27
['/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/payu/projects/folderstructure27/folder1', 
'/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/payu/projects/folderstructure27', ....,
'/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/folderstructure27/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
```

From the output we can see that `PYTHONPATH` is set to current project folder.

**Running from terminal**

Now let's run the `somecode.py` from terminal with the modifications we made.

```
$ python somecode.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somecode.py", line 2, in <module>
    print (os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])
  File "/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/folderstructure27/bin/../lib/python2.7/UserDict.py", line 40, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key)
KeyError: 'PYTHONPATH'
```

So that indicates there is no `PYTHONPATH` when we ran it in terminal. Let us run it again by removing the `print(os.environ['PYTHONPATH'])` code. You will get the below output

```
['/Users/tarun.lalwani/Desktop/payu/projects/folderstructure27/folder1', ...
'/Users/tarun.lalwani/.virtualenvs/folderstructure27/lib/python2.7/site-packages']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "somecode.py", line 7, in <module>
    from utils.myutils1 import myclass
ImportError: No module named utils.myutils1
```

As you can see `folder1` is added to `sys.path` because it is the folder containing `somecode.py`, but the root folder has not been added. The fix in terminal is simple, which is to set the root directory path in PYTHONPATH.

```
PYTHONPATH=`pwd`/.. python somcode.py
```

And now the code will work from terminal also.

But the way they work are different from Python Console.

**IMPORTANT NOTE:**
**Python Console using PyCharm on remote interpreter.**

If running the python console using the remote interpreter option pycharm will fail.  This is because it will append the path of the local PC and not the path of the remote server.
In order to fix this problem one has to add a mapping between the local PC directory and the remote server path.
[image: pycharmRemoteConfig]
[image: pycharmRemoteConfig2]

Comment: Great explanation with examples. This should be the accepted answer

Comment: @Tarun, great answer works command line now.  However, my pycharm still doesn't work.  I am closer to understand why but I cannot fix it.  I am running pycharm remote mode.  I.e., remote python 3.6.1 and it connects to an Ubuntu linux server.  By default pycharm First steps are #import sys; print('Python %s on %s' % (sys.version, sys.platform))
#sys.path.extend([WORKING_DIR_AND_PYTHON_PATHS]) which adds the folder local pc not remote server to path.  I also have copy of code in server.. so i tried import sys;
sys.path.extend('/home/DSProjectCode/') but it doesn't work on this remote config

Comment: any ideas to fix this last remote mode problem and I am all set... thanks for your help!

Comment: @TarunLalwani thanks a lot, looking forward to your thoughts.

Comment: @TarunLalwani I managed to fix it, thanks so much! I edited the answer with comments about the fix that needs to be done for remote config and accepted the answer.

Comment: @TarunLalwani yes, v v nice! this has been a frustration for months now, literally you just made my day :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `utils` package inside `folder1` folder:

[image]

Then the code will work either way:

```
from utils.myutils1 import myClass
```

Comment: the problem is that I want to be able to use it from many other folders so it'd be way better if it can live outside of folder 1 and inside project root.

Answer (score 0):

Similar error here and this appears to be working for me:

Make sure Project Interpreter is set to, for example: `C:\Python36\python.exe` *(in my case)* and not a copy somewhere or another.

'File > Settings > Project ____ > Project Interpreter'

Or, long story short, if that route isn't cooperating, can also try finding `workspace.xml` and manually change `SDK_HOME` before starting PyCharm:

```
<option name="SDK_HOME" value="C:\Python36\python.exe" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Working on these brilliant and very welcome explanations, I ended up updating my shell (git-bash) `.bashrc` file (the config script launched when opening the bash) adding the following line wherever :

```
alias python="PYTHONPATH=$(pwd)/.. python",
```

i.e creating an alias for a linux command to have a shortcut and getting free from rewriting the python path assignment all the time.

The additional thing to say is that opening your terminal in PyCharm brings you in your project folder. Then you `cd` to your `.py` folder you want to run. So actually after this `cd`, you have to reload the bash to reload the `pwd`, i.e the path.

Reloading the bash is done by typing the `bash` command. (which reruns your .`bashrc` script.)