# Why am I getting a ModuleNotFoundError when using googletrans

Tags: python, api, pycharm, google-translator-toolkit, googletrans

I have pip installed googletrans and more or less copied this code off a video but for some reason it cannot find the module.

```
from googletrans import Translator
text=("How to convert some text to multiple languages")
destination_langauge={
    "Spanish": "es",
    "Chinese":"zh-CN",
    "Italian":"it"}
translator=Translator()
for key, value in destination_language.item():
    print(tranlator.translate(text, dest=value).text)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated because I am struggling

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install `googletrans` with `pip install googletrans`. If you get a `ModulNotFoundError` you have not installed googletrans correctly.

```
from googletrans import Translator

text=("How to convert some text to multiple languages")
destination_language = {
    "Spanish": "es",
    "Chinese":"zh-CN",
    "Italian":"it"
}
translator=Translator()
for key, value in destination_language.items():
    print(translator.translate(text, dest=value).text)
```

You have multiple mistakes in your code. It's `items()` and not `item()` and the variable `translator` was misspelled in the last line.

The output of your program is:

```
Cómo convertir un texto a varios idiomas
如何将一些文本转换为多种语言
Come convertire del testo in più lingue
```

Comment: Thank you, I've made the changes but I am still getting the module not found error despite having installed it

Comment: @Shoto What does the error say in detail? Please provide the full error message.

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/jordo/Desktop/CS Coursework/Tests/api hope.py", line 1, in <module>
    from googletrans import Translator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'googletrans'

Comment: Check if you have multiple python versions installed. And check your python program from different consoles/terminals/command prompts.

Comment: Yes I did, manage to get it to work but doesn't work in Pycharm. The code works in python 3.6.2 but when I run it in pycharm the same error occurs

Comment: Do you use a other version of python in pycharm than in you local console/terminal?

Comment: Maybe, how would I change this?

Comment: Have a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46354454/modulenotfounderror-error-with-pycharm-project-folder-recs He/She explained it very detailled.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pip install googletrans for you system python means you can deactivate the virtual environment and pip install googletrans and then activate the virtualenv again.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same error and I found out the reason is that I have two Python versions installed (3.7 and 3.8) and the googletrans package was installed only for the one in system path (3.8). What I did is simply use the IDE with 3.8 (I use IDLE and PyCharm as IDE, both are easy to change Python interpreter).